# How to disable KEY-ENTER behaviour in Eclipse RCP PreferencePage

Tags: eclipse, default, rcp, behavior

in my application I have several preference-pages. In some of them the user has to edit a few items. If the user uses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key-KEY the whole Preference Dialog closes, caused by the fact, that the OK-Button has the focus.

So how can I disable this behaviour?

I can set the focus on any item on the page, but pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> forces the dialog to close.

Comment: have you solve your problem? I am facing exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the default Dialog and override the following method.

```
@Override
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
    // Its the same as super.createButtonsForButtonBar(), but makes no default buttons by sending false.
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL, false);
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);
}
```

Comment: This doed not solve my problem. I don't use any instance of dialog. Instead I'm using a preference-page (org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage). There is no method for overwiting the buttons default behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code on your target widget

```
widget.addListener(SWT.Traverse, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
    if (e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN)
        e.doit = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: OK. It will be helpful: this traverse listener is used to disable the [enter] key pressed operation when users want activate the default [OK] button in a dialog.